# Wait Function not working Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization, wait

I am using Android Studio. I am trying to fix a clock in which I pressed the button, it will return the time to 12:00. I got it working but I want it to be executed by waiting 250 miliseconds. The problem is that they only wait for 250 miliseconds (but there are two executions so that's 5 seconds) and then it goes to 12:00 right away without showing it to the Text View. Is there something I am doing wrong? Also if I applied handler function here, I'm afraid I don't have much knowledge to use that.

Edit: This is from my MainActivity method. Example, change from 1 to 2 then wait for 250 miliseconds, change from 2 to 3 then wait for 250 miliseconds

```
synchronized (this){
    try {
        while(minuteHand != 0 || hourHand != 12){
            if (hourHand != 12){
                hourHand++;
                hourText.setText(Integer.toString(hourHand));
                wait(250);
            }
            if (minuteHand != 0) {
                minuteHand += 5;
                minuteHand %= 60;
                minuteText.setText(Integer.toString(minuteHand));
                wait(250);
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the proper way to update UI elements from an asynchronous thread:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView hourText;
    private TextView minuteText;

    private void updateHourText(final String text) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hourText.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateMinuteText(final String text) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                minuteText.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }

    private class ClockTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        private int hourHand;
        private int minuteHand;


        public ClockTask(int hourHand, int minuteHand) {
            this.hourHand = hourHand;
            this.minuteHand = minuteHand;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                while(minuteHand != 0 || hourHand != 12){
                    if (hourHand != 12){
                        hourHand++;
                        updateHourText(Integer.toString(hourHand));
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    }
                    if (minuteHand != 0) {
                        minuteHand += 5;
                        minuteHand %= 60;
                        updateMinuteText(Integer.toString(minuteHand));
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then call this from your button's `onClickListener()`:

```
new ClockTask(hourHand, minuteHand).execute();
```

As you can see, in order to update `TextView`'s text, a helper method was needed, which would always execute `TextView.setText()` inside your main thread. That way, your business logic can execute within its own thread (without causing main thread to wait, which would lead to unresponsive UI), while updating your `TextView`s asynchronously.

Also, you should never try to update UI elements outside your main thread's context as it will lead to an exception being thrown.

Comment: Isn't Thread not a good idea to use? But either way, I will still try. Also, I don't think I can call that to the MainActivity because it is in Private. I called it like this     `new SampleActivity.ClockTask(hourHand, minuteHand).execute();`

Comment: You could use Thread instead of AsyncTask. What do you mean when you say it is private ? Maybe you could provide some more code and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Erm, I am trying to call the code you made to my MainActivity. Then I tried doing: `SampleActivity act = new SampleActivity();` then on the bottom `act.ClockTask(hourHand,minuteHand).execute();`

Comment: No, no. `SampleActivity` is just for an example. Copy paste `ClockTask` class, `updateHourText()` and `updateMinuteText()` methods in to your `MainActivity` and from there you can call from anywhere you want `new ClockTask(hourHand, minuteHand).execute();`.

Comment: Ohhhh. I see. I will go try it now :)

Comment: Thank you for the help but it still forces close whether it was on thread or I put it on wait when I generated it into an APK. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Could you update your question with the whole `MainActivity` and the stack trace of the crash, so that I could further assist you ? I don't believe that my code is causing the crash.

Comment: Sorry... it didn't work at first because I changed the data type of int into byte when I transferred it to the other side. I think Thread does not take Byte types so that's why. Anyways, it works now because I changed it back to Int type. Thank you :)